# How to make authored on field emtpy

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a content type with revision enabled, each time when I edit the node I can see **authored on** field has `created date` by default. I want this  field to be empty so that it uses latest updated time as created time. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Why not just use the modified date? That's what it's for...

Comment: I want to update created date too.

Comment: I'm with @Clive I think you are using created date incorrectly. If you want the modified date use the modified date. Changing created date on every update is kind of pointless and borders on database corruption.

Comment: @danielson317 - I think the reason might be that he want every new revision to be marked as created when the revision is first created from the original version?

Comment: @Cyclone you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use rules 'After updating existing content of type typename' in events and 'set data value' timestamp to created date will accomplish your task easily.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x) to accomplish this. Something like this might work:

```
function hook_node_presave($node) {
   // check so the node if of a specific type and a revision
   if ($node->type == 'your-type' && $node->revision == TRUE) {
     // sets creation date equal to the modification date
     $node->created = $node->modified;
   }
}
```

The above would go in a custom module file and you then have to rename the `hook` part to the actual name of your module.